# How can you print out the values of undeclared HTML form values from a Spring (3) controller action method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, forms

If my HTML form contains two form inputs (`input1` and `input2`), I could access them like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String foo(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap modelMap,
    @RequestParam(value = "input1") String input1,
    @RequestParam(value = "input2") String input2)
{
            log.write("input1=" + input1);
            log.write("input2=" + input2);

    return "redirect:/foo/";
}
```

But what if I have other form elements on the HTML page that I don't know about?

How can I print out the values of form elements that I have not declared in the action method with a `@RequestParam` annotation?

Comment: "But what if I have other form elements on the HTML page that I don't know about?" - use the org.springframework.clairvoyance.MindReader interface.  That should let Spring figure it out, even if you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `HttpServletRequest` - `request.getParameterNames()` this will get all the submitted parameters.